# Get Postal Codes from GeoNames

Tags: geonames

I have a requirement to lookup for Zip Code(Postal Code) and get City ,Latitude and Longitude.
Does Geonames has a file that supports this format ?

I downloaded AllCountries.txt and that does not contain the postal codes.

Here is the table structure i created  for allcountries.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AllCountries](
 [geonameid] [int] NOT NULL,
 [name] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [asciiname] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [alternatenames] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [latitude] [float] NULL,
 [longitude] [float] NULL,
 [feature_class] [char](2) NULL,
 [feature_code] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [country_code] [char](3) NULL,
 [cc2] [char](60) NULL,
 [admin1_code] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [admin2_code] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
 [admin3_code] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [admin4_code] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [population] [bigint] NULL,
 [elevation] [int] NULL,
 [dem] [int] NULL,
 [timezone] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [modification_date] [date] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [geonameid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

How can i get all Postal Codes from all countries, along with city and coordinates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Geonames API to return JSON data. You provide postal code and it returns the country and lat and lang info.

http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username=demo

here is a page with more examples. Look around the webservices documentation also:
http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#postalCodeLookupJSON

link to an example:
http://www.geonames.org/export/ajax-postalcode-autocomplete-3.html